# Write multiple numpy arrays to file

Tags: python, numpy, io

I know how to use numpy.savetxt to write an array to a file.  How can I write multiple arrays to the same file?

Essentially I want to do math to a column of numbers, and then replace the old column with the modified numbers.  I read the easiest way to do this is to write a new file completely, put the modified numbers in, and just 'copy and paste' the other numbers in the file.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

Answering a very old post for my own use. I've used the following to write out two 1D arrays of same size as CSV.

```
import numpy as np

x = [1, 2, 3]
y = [4, 5, 6]
zipped = zip(x, y)
# >>> [(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6)]

# Save the array back to the file
np.savetxt('z.csv', zipped, fmt='%i,%i')
```

Comment: This seems nice, but does not work on Python 3. Here, an `IndexError` is thrown by NumPy.

Answer (score 6):

If you're wanting to write multiple arrays to a file for later use, Look into [numpy.savez](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savez.html).

However, from your description, it sounds like you're wanting to do something with a particular column of a delimited text file.

In that case, just load the entire thing in and operate on just the column you need to.

E.g.

```
import numpy as np

data = np.loadtxt('test.txt')

# Multiply the 4th column by 5
data[:,3] *= 5

# Do something more complicated to the 2nd column
data[:,1] = np.cos(data[:,1])

# Save the array back to the file
np.savetxt('test.txt', data)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy


list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]

list2 = [0.45, 0.98, 0.89, 0.21]

dat = numpy.array([list1, list2])

dat = dat.T

numpy.savetxt('data.txt', dat, delimiter = ',')
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow and thanks for trying to help. Please explain your code-only answer.

Comment: Doesn't work: get Mismatch between array dtype ('object') and format specifier ('%.18e')