# How to export the n dimensional array(Python Numpy) into text file?

Tags: python, numpy

I have matrix , which presented as 2 dimensional array.
It seems like I can use numpy.ndarray.tofile to export it into text file, but it just generate everything in one line.
How can I get text file in matrix format(say, one line is one row in matrix)?
like

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

instead of

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

Answer (score 4):

Consult this post about writing numpy arrays to files: [Write multiple numpy arrays to file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3419082/write-multiple-numpy-arrays-to-file)

The code should be something like:

```
#data is a numpy array
data = numpy.array([[1, 2, 3],[4, 5, 6],[7, 8, 9]])


# Save the array back to the file
np.savetxt('test.txt', data)
```

This yields the following (almost human-readable) output:

```
1.000000000000000000e+00 2.000000000000000000e+00 3.000000000000000000e+00
4.000000000000000000e+00 5.000000000000000000e+00 6.000000000000000000e+00
7.000000000000000000e+00 8.000000000000000000e+00 9.000000000000000000e+00
```

Answer (score -1):

```
with open('path/to/file', 'w') as outfile:
    for row in matrix:
        outfile.write(' '.join([str(num) for num in row]))
        outfile.write('\n')
```