# Streaming multiple numpy arrays to a file

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, file-io, binaryfiles

This differs from [Write multiple numpy arrays to file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3419082/write-multiple-numpy-arrays-to-file) in that I need to be able to stream content, rather than writing it all at once.

I need to write multiple compressed numpy arrays in binary to a file. I can not store all the arrays in memory before writing so it is more like streaming numpy arrays to a file.

This currently works fine as text

file = open("some file")

while doing stuff:
  file.writelines(somearray + "\n")
where some array is a new instance every loop

however this does not work if i try and write the arrays as binary.

arrays are created at 30hz and grow too big to keep in memory. They also can not each be stored into a bunch of single array files because that would just be wasteful and cause a huge mess.

So i would like only one file per a session instead of 10k files per a session.

Comment: Do all the arrays have the same shape and data type?  You say *"... however this does not work if i try and write the arrays as binary"*, but you didn't explain how you attempted to do this, and what went wrong.  Please give more details about what you tried.

Comment: they do not have the same shape.

What went wrong was the file was empty

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option might be to use pickle to save the arrays to a file opened as an `append binary` file:

```
import numpy as np
import pickle
arrays = [np.arange(n**2).reshape((n,n)) for n in range(1,11)]
with open('test.file', 'ab') as f:
    for array in arrays:
        pickle.dump(array, f)

new_arrays = []        
with open('test.file', 'rb') as f:
    while True:
        try:
            new_arrays.append(pickle.load(f))
        except EOFError:
            break
assert all((new_array == array).all() for new_array, array in zip(new_arrays, arrays))
```

This might not be the fastest, but it should be fast enough. It might seem like this would take up more data, but comparing these:

```
x = 300
y = 300
arrays = [np.random.randn(x, y) for x in range(30)]

with open('test2.file', 'ab') as f:
    for array in arrays:
        pickle.dump(array, f)

with open('test3.file', 'ab') as f:
    for array in arrays:
        f.write(array.tobytes())

with open('test4.file', 'ab') as f:
    for array in arrays:
        np.save(f, array)
```

You'll find the file sizes as 1,025 KB, 1,020 KB, and 1,022 KB respectively.

Comment: How do you then load the arrays again? If I say `np.load('test4.file')` I just get the first one.

Comment: My first snippet describes how to load the arrays; lines 8-14 are loading from the writing that is done in lines 1-6.

Comment: A bit hacky, but pretty efficient :)

Comment: The other solution by Warren is more along the lines of what you'd expect to do using numpy constructs, however, the problem is that each new array means reading out all of the old arrays; thus, to create a file from a stream of n arrays, it would take O(n^2) time. With appending the binary, building a file from n arrays only takes O(n) time.

Comment: good point, though the n^2 behaviour should only happen if you keep closing/opening the file. If you just keep adding to the file as in Warren's code you should get linear behaviour. But again, sometimes you may need to close the file, so point well taken.

Answer (score 4):

An NPZ file is just a zip archive, so you could save each array to a temporary NPY file, add that NPY file to the zip archive, and then delete the temporary file.

For example,

```
import os
import zipfile
import numpy as np


# File that will hold all the arrays.
filename = 'foo.npz'

with zipfile.ZipFile(filename, mode='w', compression=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED) as zf:
    for i in range(10):
        # `a` is the array to be written to the file in this iteration.
        a = np.random.randint(0, 10, size=20)

        # Name for the temporary file to which `a` is written.  The root of this
        # filename is the name that will be assigned to the array in the npz file.
        # I've used 'arr_{}' (e.g. 'arr_0', 'arr_1', ...), similar to how `np.savez`
        # treats positional arguments.
        tmpfilename = "arr_{}.npy".format(i)

        # Save `a` to a npy file.
        np.save(tmpfilename, a)

        # Add the file to the zip archive.
        zf.write(tmpfilename)

        # Delete the npy file.
        os.remove(tmpfilename)
```

Here's an example where that script is run, and then the data is read back using `np.load`:

```
In [1]: !ls
add_array_to_zip.py

In [2]: run add_array_to_zip.py

In [3]: !ls
add_array_to_zip.py foo.npz

In [4]: foo = np.load('foo.npz')

In [5]: foo.files
Out[5]: 
['arr_0',
 'arr_1',
 'arr_2',
 'arr_3',
 'arr_4',
 'arr_5',
 'arr_6',
 'arr_7',
 'arr_8',
 'arr_9']

In [6]: foo['arr_0']
Out[6]: array([0, 9, 3, 7, 2, 2, 7, 2, 0, 5, 8, 1, 1, 0, 4, 2, 5, 1, 8, 2])
```

You'll have to test this on your system to see if it can keep up with your array generation process.

---

Another alternative is to use something like HDF5, with either [h5py](http://www.h5py.org/) or [pytables](http://www.pytables.org/).

Comment: How would you continuously add arrays to the `.npz` file?

Comment: My answer is an example of how to do that, isn't it?

Comment: Using your answer, how would I append ten new arrays to `foo.npz`? I think you want to use `mode='a'`.

Comment: Ah, I see.  My answer assumes that you will create the file, and then repeatedly add arrays to it.  Yes, you would need to use `mode='a'` for the zipfile if you want to add to an existing file.  You would also need to ensure that the name used for each array does not already exist in the NPZ file.

Comment: I believe that's what he would want. Assume that arrays are yielded from a possibly infinite generator which can be halted and resumed at any time; that's what I'd take "streaming" as.

Comment: There are too many details missing from the question for me to start guessing what he wants.  The question refers to a bunch of arrays being generated in a "session".  My answer assumes a "session" is one run of a program, and that one file is to be created for that session.